# Domain of existence of $x^y$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

What is the domain of existence of $f(x,y)=x^y$?

I think that it is $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x>0$ because $y$ can ben any real.

However, the function in defined $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ for positive integer $y$...

Comment: Do you allow complex numbers?  Do you disallow $(-1)^{1/3}$?  You will need to specify what the purpose is for your definition.  My recommendation: wait until you study complex analysis.

Comment: *Existence* is a hard word in maths.

Answer (score 1):

You have almost answered your question. Assuming you only want to consider Real numbers and not complex.

It's the union of the two sets you mention (for x<0 you can have integer y, not only positive integer), plus what happens at x=0. Domain of existence is
$\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x>0, y \in \mathbb{R} \} \cup \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x <0, y \in \mathbb{Z} \} \cup \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x=0 , y>0\} $

Answer (score 1):

It depends on context.

Exponentiation is typically defined on a restricted domain, and each expansion of that domain comes with caveats or new formalisms.

1. We usually start with $x\geq 0$ and $y$ a positive integer.  In this context exponentiation is just defined as repeated multiplication.
2. By restricting $x>0$ we can expand further the domain of exponentiation with $y\in \mathbb{Q}$ in terms of roots and reciprocals.  And $x=0$ is no problem in this context as long as $y>0$.
3. In order to further expand the domain to the open half plane ($x>0$, $y\in \mathbb{R}$), we need to use limits.  Specifically, consider that we want $x^y$ to be continuous in both $x$ and $y$, and approach $y$ with a sequence of rational numbers.
4. Sometimes, too, $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is given a value, but this is more of a convention, since the limit does not exist. Said another way: the limit is dependent on how you approach $(0,0)$.
5. In order to further expand the domain, one needs to use complex numbers.  This begins by letting $i:=(-1)^\frac{1}{2}$ and following where that leads.
6. Armed with $i$, we can define $f(z)=e^z$ and $g(z) = \ln z$.  The first is defined for all complex $z$.  The second has some problems around the origin.  Without getting too deep, this lets you define $\ln z$ for any $z\not = 0$, but you will have a discontinuity somewhere in a line extending out to infinity.  Typically, the discontinuity is placed on the negative real axis.
7. Using step 6, alongside the observation that $a^b = e^{b\ln a}$, we can extend exponentiation to everywhere $\ln z$ is defined.  Since $\ln z$ is a function not without "problems", we typically need to make sure at this stage everyone is on the same page with exactly what "version" of $\ln z$ we're using.
8. Here's where it usually stops, though if you want to give up certain nice properties of your numbers, you can keep going to the quaternions, octonions, etc.

All that is to say, one could reasonably claim that $x\in \mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty, 0]$, and $y\in \mathbb{C}$ is the usual "extended" domain of $x^y$, but the value depends on what "branch" of the [complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm) you're using.  At the very least, best not to throw the values around without first understanding complex numbers.